# Batch-file to Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell, batch-file, cmd

I am currently struggling to convert this cmd script into bash:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET /P USERBACKUPSOURCE= SOURCE:
SET /P USERBACKUPDEST= DESTINATION:

XCOPY /W %USERBACKUPSOURCE% %USERBACKUPDEST%
```

I don't really know much about linux so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you mean `bash` ? I think "shell" is a generic term, OS-agnostic (cmd.exe can be considered as a shell, although it is true that often more Linux related).

Comment: Are you **really** using MS-DOS? Or are you referring to the command line in Windows?

Comment: Sorry edited it, I meant bash and cmd scripts @kebs

Comment: you have to try something yourself first and then ask if struggle. there are many ways to copy files in bash if that's what you mean by shell: cp, rsync ...

Comment: and "read" command instead of "set /p" for user input

Comment: I was using rsync but I thought I did something wrong because I can't see the copied files. Let me try this again @Vairis

Comment: In the future, you should describe what the dos batch script is doing if you need help converting it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SET /p equivalent in linux is "read -p"
read -p 'Please enter SOURCE dir (ex: /root/source/) : ' source
read -p 'Please enter DESTINATION dir (ex: /root/destination/) : ' destination

#xcopy /w : Displays the following message and waits for your response before starting to copy files:
#Press any key to begin copying file(s)

read -r -p "Copy $source to $destination? [y/N] " response
if [[ $response =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]]
then
        #cp -i, --interactive: prompt before overwrite
        #cp -R, -r, --recursive: copy directories recursively
        cp -i -r $source $destination
else
        echo "Aborted"
fi
```